# Can't decode JSON file in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I try to decode JSON in PHP To array.
This is my code

```
<?php
$url="file/game.json";
$result_file=file_get_contents($url);
    if(!$result_file){ echo 'result_file......Failed'; }
$php_result=json_decode($result_file,true);
print_r($php_result);

if($php_result){

    echo 'ok';
}
else{

    echo 'error';
}
?>
```

AND  this is my json file

```
[
  {
    "name": "ABCD",
    "price": "24.36",
    "platform": "<span class=\"platform battle-net\"></span>",
    "region": "GLOBAL"
  },
  {
    "name": "ABCD",
    "price": "27.60",
    "platform": "<span class=\"platform xbox-live\"></span>",
    "region": "GLOBAL"
  }
]
```

My result Is "error". And I don't no know how to solve this problem.

What should I do.

Comment: your script is ok just make sure $url="file/game.json"; file found?

Comment: You code works for me too. Probably, you don't get data into `$result_file`.

Comment: what does print `print_r($php_result);` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) function returns the entire file into a string or `FALSE` on failure. So I assume, here you're not getting the file string. So try like this way,

```
<?php
try {
    $url="file/game.json";
    $result_file = file_get_contents('file/game.json');
    if ($result_file === false) {
        // Handle the error
        echo "ERROR";
    }else{
        $php_result=json_decode($result_file,true);

        switch (json_last_error()) {
            case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
            echo ' - OK';
            print_r($php_result);
            break;
            case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
            echo ' - Maximum stack depth exceeded';
            break;
            case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
            echo ' - Underflow or the modes mismatch';
            break;
            case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
            echo ' - Unexpected control character found';
            break;
            case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
            echo ' - Syntax error, malformed JSON';
            break;
            case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
            echo ' - Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded';
            break;
            default:
            echo ' - Unknown error';
            break;
        }
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Handle exception
    #echo $e->getMessage();
    #echo $e->code();
}
?>
```

Comment: how this code handle the fact that `$result_file` is `false` ?

Comment: If result_file is false then Json will also be false

Comment: Ohh, It was my bad, *Edited*

Comment: With your new edit you have opened up for a new error. If the file_get_contents works but the Json is malformed the json_decode will be false, yet your code will say "ok"

Comment: you can maybe add `json_last_error_msg` in case of empty ` $php_result` or checking `json_last_error`

Comment: In my opinion the original edit was correct. The Json would fail if file_get_contents fails thus return error

Comment: the OP does not why it does not work so add those tests will help him to know